# What is the equivelent of a java .properties file in Powershell v2?

Tags: properties, import, powershell-2.0

I want to include some common variables between a pair of powershell scripts so that their values are only set in one place.  Is it possible to import the values of some variables in Powershell v2, so that they are set in a file that both scripts can read?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the variable definitions to a PowerShell script

```psh
# include.ps1
$foo = 23
```

and [dot-source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176949.aspx) that script in your other scripts.

```psh
# run.ps1

# Defaults
$foo = 42
echo $foo

# Properties file...
. .\include.ps1
echo $foo
```

---

Output:

```
PS C:\> .\run.ps1
42
23
```